# Optional date parameter using Route attribute in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I want to have two endpoints to my API method:

`api/bids/`

and

`api/bids/{yyyy-MM-dd}`

In first case i will map undefined date as today

I tried to make this way, but it did not work:

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/bids")]
    public class BidsController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet, Route("api/bids/{dateTime?}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBids(DateTime? dateTime = null)
        {

            var correctDate = (dateTime != null) && (dateTime.Value >= DateTime.Now.Date);
            DateTime date = correctDate ? dateTime.Value : DateTime.Now.Date;

            try
            {
                return Ok(date);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = ex.Message;
                return BadRequest(errorMessage);
            }

        }
    }
```

How i can use optional date parameter with attribute routing in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your parameter optional within the route as well as the default null assigning:

Also your Endpoint route needs to be changed to not include api/bids

```
[RoutePrefix("api/bids")]
public class BidsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("{dateTime:DateTime?}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBids(DateTime? dateTime = null)
    {

        var correctDate = (dateTime != null) && (dateTime.Value >= DateTime.Now.Date);
        DateTime date = correctDate ? dateTime.Value : DateTime.Now.Date;

        try
        {
            return Ok(date);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = ex.Message;
            return BadRequest(errorMessage);
        }

    }
}
```

For ease of reading, I have changed this line

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/bids/{dateTime?}")]
```

to this

```
[HttpGet, Route("{dateTime:DateTime?}")]
```

Comment: This approach returns a 404 error for both `/api/bids/` and `/api/bids/2019-01-01` requests.

Comment: This might be completely wrong, as haven't used Route prefix in a while. But doesn't your setup cause the route to be api/bids/api/bids/2019-01-01 - Let me know if that fixes the issue and I will change my answer to use correct routing also

Comment: Can you just try changing the Endpoint route to this: [HttpGet, Route("{dateTime:DateTime?}")] Let me know if that fixes your issue, if not then I am out of ideas...

Comment: It works fine thanx! I understand that problem was related with duplicated RoutePrefix

Comment: No problem, just changed my original answer to reflect this